# How to make the 1st part of the site loads first? (Like in Google PageSpeed)

Tags: php, html, performance, optimization, pagespeed

I have a very large site and it takes pretty long time to load. It takes around 120 seconds. What I'm trying to do is loads 1st half of the site loads 1st. Then user can surf while others parts are being loaded.

What I'm trying to do is below.

[image]

- **1st of all is this possible ?**

According to my knowledge Yes since Google PageSpeed does that. But the problem is if I use PageSpeed I would have to change my DNS server settings and etc. I would like to do this myself.

- **How can I get it done ?**
- **What type of technology should I use ?**

Given that pages have the `.php` extension and written in PHP language.

Comment: Are any of the images dynamically generated? How many do you have?

Comment: If you research on pagespeed it allows you to do the above scenario using their server by changing DNS to their server. What I want to do is do it myself. Just to load the 1st part of the like shown above and the rest of it. Given done CSS and JS optimization and using minified version at the moment.

Comment: 120seconds?? To load a page? Thats crazy. Is the delay in the 'rendering' of the page - or is it for the server to generate the page? i.e. do you have a PHP script that is doing some massive database pulling or something?

Comment: None as such. Just a long page.

Comment: Dasun given you want to do this in PHP I think you want Bigpipe [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14948458/318174).

Comment: Why do you have the large page in the first place? If a page takes over 10 seconds to load, you have a design flaw to begin with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the concept of lazy loading.

You can load only content that is necessary during the load then using jquery and ajax you can load the remaining content.

In this way user can surf and interact easily with the the part already loaded while the other part will be loading asynchronously.

jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method can help you on this.

A simple example could be,

If There are 5 parts of contents in your page, 2 needs to be loaded immediately

1. The page will be loaded with 2 parts loaded, so it will take quite less time than 5 parts loading
2. After document is loaded you will use ajax to load the remaining 3 parts.
   Ajax will send request to the specific page of your website(can be possibly named AjaxRequestHandler.php) with some parameters, and this page will process your request and generate html for this and will send it back to your main page which will just show this returned html and this all be happening asynchronously, so the user will be able to communicate with the initially loaded 2 parts

And even if you are new to web technologies, I suppose you have to have the knowledge of atleast ajax and asynchronous calls etc. to achieve lazy loading.

**Edit :**

For your this question

> Except AJAX Is there way around for this?

I think you can try iframes if they can help.

Loading the main content in the page load without iframe while loading other contents in the iframes after pages is loaded.

This jsFiddle

jsfiddle.net/cGDuV/

can help you understand lazy loading with iframe, mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154958/lazy-load-iframe-delay-src-http-call-with-jquery) of stackoverflow.

You can use javascript for the same if you want to avoid jquery.

Comment: Also check out the LazyLoad jquery plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 9):

You can manipulate the output buffer such that it flushes early thus achieving what your after in the screenshot you posted in your question. 
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/01/31/http-archive-adding-flush/

You can lazyload all your images. Here's a jquery plugin that does it easily
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

You can combine all your js in one file. Same with your css files. This will help the speed.

You can incorporate caching, expires headers and gzip/deflate compression
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

I would suggest you load your 3rd party javascript widget garbage (Google+ buttons, fabebook like buttons, social, twitter stuff) in a non blocking asynchronous way so it does not slow down the page in the beginning.
http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/

Optimize your images as much as possible.
http://kraken.io/

Use a CDN
http://www.maxcdn.com/

Finally test your site and see where is the big bottleneck and where you can improve the site for speed optimization. Use the waterfall chart feature
http://www.webpagetest.org/

Comment: here's a link on how to make css and js files into one..http://aciddrop.com/2008/01/03/automatically-join-your-javascript-and-css-into-a-single-file/  which reduces the number of http requests for improved site performance..

Comment: @Lucky That script is dated January 2008, and likely not maintained anymore. It also uses `preg_` matching to parse out the script tags and rebuild the page which would add to your TTFB overhead. I would not recommend using that. There's so many better and modern ways to concatenate and minify files.  You could use a task runner for instance like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

Answer (score 3):

One of the things you can do is to load all the essential (top half) of the page normally, then use javascript/ajax to load the second half of the page. This is a very common technique (and is often used to load images).

Here is an excellent tutorial from jQuery for Designers, walking through how to use jQuery to load images asynchronously after the page loads. http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

Having said that, a two minute load time seems very excessive. Maybe you should check if there is anything that could be slowing down your server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to determine why the site is loading slow. What is the size of the data you are sending? Google and Firefox have web developer tools to help you determine which elements are taking the longest too load. Once you've determined the culprit, try to load the worst offenders asynchronously.

Check out this article on aync requests: https://segment.io/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/

Answer (score 3):

in my opinion you need an endless scrolling solution. That is, have a fixed amount of content per "page" (could be an estimated 1500px worth of height). Use jQuery to load another "page" when user scrolls down by a set amount.

If you really want to unconditionally load all the content, just use the same approach, and on document ready trigger the next page to load. The loop the page loader until the whole thing is loaded. That way, you load the first "page", and defer the content "below the fold" to subsequent requests.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is what Facebook does [**Bigpipe**](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919) and here is a relevant SO post: [Facebook Bigpipe Technique Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106651/facebook-bigpipe-technique-algorihtm)

There are other solutions involving all sorts of Javascript but since you want **PHP** and Facebook uses **PHP** you should read up on Bigpipe. [Juho even has an example written in PHP](http://www.juhonkoti.net/2010/10/01/open-bigpipe-javascript-implementation) so that should meet your PHP requirements (but yes it still requires js but not AJAX).

Answer (score 2):

*Prefetching Resources* the web page require large files for loading can often benefited from changing the order that those files are requested from the server. Sometimes, it makes sense to download files before they are necessary, so that they are instantly available once requested. When the resources required for a page can be loaded in advance, the user-perceived network latency for that page can be significantly reduced or even eliminated. When you run Google pagespeed insights and see the result, you will see how the fix the problems in your website.

Some tips to load site faster:

- Make fewer HTTP requests
- Add a far-future expires header
- Gzip your   page's components
- Minify your JavaScript, CSS and HTML

One more thing when loading a webpage and if you are using php with smarty you can use this [plugin](http://aciddrop.com/2008/01/03/automatically-join-your-javascript-and-css-into-a-single-file/) which reduces the number of http requests to you server and makes the site load faster by combining all the js and css resource's request into one single HTTP request.

Alternatively you might be looking for these plugins.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Does all this stuff *have* to be on the same page? Does it make sense to split the content over multiple pages? Can some of it be delayed until the person requests it? Can it be grouped into tabs? Hidden tabs could be lazy loaded for instance.

Give serious thought to restructuring the content in other ways. You might be able to come up with an alternate arrangement that simplifies the problem.

Comment: It's not possible to split into pages as I have to keep all the stuff in a single page.

Answer (score 1):

Having in mind all that was mentioned above you may think of caching parts of your data/html code with memcache or in any other way possible so you skip its generation every time. Of course this depends pretty much on how often the data changes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't browsers render the document as it comes in? Whatever you put at the top of the file will be received by the client first, and therefore will be displayed first. For example, when you try to view a very large image file online, it loads from top to bottom. The same is true for web pages. Just put the content you want to load first at the top of the page!

Answer to question one: yes
Answer to question two: above
Answer to question three: Nothing, just put the page in the correct order.

Comment: No they don't ... not all of them, not all the time; that depends on the received html as well as on user settings.

Answer (score 1):

Well the idea is more or less the same as described by Pawan Nogariya above. You will need to fetch views and data asynchronously and then display these. But this means that you will never redirect or post back to any other page rather will get every view via ajaz. This will make you application SPA (Single Page Application) like Gmail. And, this will also mean you need to keep track of what has been renedered and what not, leaving you in a mess. So, instead of doing everything your way there are already developed and popular frameworks available that let you do that but they also make it SPA. Which means that your application doesnt "posts" to the server as in redirection but everything is doen using Ajax.

You can use Backbone ([Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)), Knockout ([Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)) and may others to achieve this. These are javascript based frameworks that help achieving what you have just asked and may expample and tutorials are also easily available. You can use it with any language as we are using it with C# (MVC) for a relatively large applicaiton.

Answer (score 1):

this is going to be ugly! You should **definitely** consider using ajax calls to load page fragments AFTER a first content stage is loaded!
This is going to break almost all known web standards, but it might render the website in parts....

this being said: here's the ugly stuff

First: get rid of the `<html>` tag of your website, start with the `<head>` DO NOT use a `<body>` tag either.
Now send your html-code in the order you want it to be loaded (top first) using `echo ...`
after each closing tag of a group (say `</table>` or `</div>`) use `flush(); ob_flush();` this will send all known content to the browser immediately.
The browser now decides if it can render the known content or not and if it will (based on the browser specifics and user settings) but with few exceptions it will.
some browsers like to wait for the closing body-tag that's why we dropped it, others even wait for the closing html tag (safari afair) that's why we dropped that too.
If you use the echo-flush scenario wisely you should be able to split the page into renderable parts which most browsers will display without an error.

**Again... don't do it this way.. it's bad, ugly and not even near any web standards**

But you asked for it.

Answer (score 1):

For your this question

> Except AJAX Is there way around for this?

I think you can try iframes if they can help.

Loading the main content in the page load without iframe while loading other contents in the iframes after pages is loaded.

This jsFiddle

jsfiddle.net/cGDuV/

can help you understand lazy loading with iframe, mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154958/lazy-load-iframe-delay-src-http-call-with-jquery) of stackoverflow.

You can use javascript for the same if you want to avoid jquery.

Answer (score -2):

With pure PHP? Not smart.

`$(function() {
 $('#body').delay(1).fadeOut();
});`

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/

Comment: well, I did. So its a very large page, assuming it requires a lot of resources, have you considered a CDN like cachefly or cloudflare?